# How to avoid keyboard control to audio in JS

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api, mediaelement

I have a very simple application that will display typing audio when user typing something and will stop the audio when user stop typing.

Here is the code:

```js
let audio = new Audio('https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/768')
let timeout;
let input = document.querySelector('input')
input.onkeydown=function(){
    window.clearTimeout(timeout)
   audio.play()
   
}
input.onkeyup= function(){
    window.clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(()=>{audio.pause()},1000);
}
```

```html
<input></input>
```

However, I found that there is a start/stop audio/video key (F8 key in some keyboard) on my keyboard and if user pressed this key, the typing audio will be played. "

Is there a way that I could avoid this from happening?

Thanks for any responds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question!  The answer is that the browser assumes anything in a standard media element is controllable externally, so play/pause control can be done by keyboards, Bluetooth controllers, lock screen controls, etc.

A solution is to use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) for playback instead.  This is probably better for your use case anyway, as it gives you more control over the buffering and timing of your audio sample.

You'll first get the audio source data, decode it to a PCM buffer, and then play it back through an [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode).  Untested code, but try something like this in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
// Set up audio context and source node
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

// Make HTTP request for audio data
const res = await fetch('https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/768');
if (!res.ok) {
  throw res.status;
}

// Get the raw data and decode it to PCM
sourceNode.buffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(
  await res.arrayBuffer()
);

// Start playback
sourceNode.start();
```

Note that you should only create this audio context when there is user interaction.  If you want to create it early, you can always call [`.resume()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/resume) with user interaction.  This is required to avoid autoplay policy issues

Hopefully this gets you started!

Comment: Really thanks for the answer. So we are using React.js to solve this ?

Comment: @James What does React have to do with it?

Comment: my problem, I just think you are using React.js. Another question, I directly use your code, but it produces:`Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` . Do you know how to solve it? Thank you so much!

Comment: No, React.js has nothing to do with this code.  As for async/await, follow the link in the answer:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function  By using async/await, you won't have to worry about a large number of nested Promise chains.  Your code still runs asynchronously, but the syntax is more straightforward.  Basically, wrap all that in `async function someFunction() { ... }`, and call that function on user input.

Comment: I try my best to understand the code. The simple `destination` will produce `undefined` error, so I change it to `audioContext.destination`, but then it shows `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`. Do you know how to solve it or is it my problem? Sorry for my ignorance, I haven't deal with `async` and await function before.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, yes it should be `audioContext.destination`.  As for the failed to fetch message, check the network tab of your developer tools to see what the error is.  Usually a 404, meaning not found.  However, it's possible your source does not support CORS... in which case you won't be able to use the AudioContext.  If the source is your server, you can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to fix it.  If it's someone else's, you'll have to download the MP3 and serve it from your own server.

Comment: It produces the 768 error and displays `Ensure CORS response header values are valid`. Is there way I could solve it?

Comment: Yes, either add the header as I mentioned above (if this is your server), or download this MP3 and serve it on your own server where you can control this header.

Comment: See also:  https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Hi, Brad, after get to a little bit deeper in fetch api and async function, it seems that the solution you give is not pure client-side which means is need to deal with server-side since fetch api doesn't support local file. Am I correct? Thank you!

Comment: @James This is purely client-side code.  Fetch API isn't needed if you have a File reference... you can get an array buffer directly.